# StoreReview: Native rating modal doesn't display on all users devices

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, expo

Store Review docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/storereview/

Hello, we have a problem with the opening of the app review modal with Expo, that only a minor part of users already well selected seem to see and go through the end of rating process. Many click to see it voluntarily and only a minor part actually publish a review.

We have an application with an app review flow customized to optimize good reviews by targeting specific users already using our app regularly.
Before showing the native app rating modal, we display a previous modal asking if the user want to review us or not. And this previous modal is displayed at the end of a flow of usage of our app, so not disturbing the user up front when he just opened the app.

But actually, we go from 50 logs of clicks to open the native rating modal to 8 review added to our app store / play store in total.

Our app already only supports SDKs recent enough to support native rating modal.

Would you know what could be failing that much ?

Here is our code to launch the native rating modal via events coming from our web app in our website (using a webview as a PWA)

```
if (message.nativeEvent.data.startsWith('request-review')) {
    StoreReview.hasAction().then((hasAction) => {
        if (hasAction) {
            StoreReview.requestReview().then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            const reviewUrl = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Constants.manifest.extra.ios_review_url : Constants.manifest.extra.android_review_url;
            Linking.openURL(reviewUrl);
        }
    });
}
```